# How can I share a return value in recursive function?

Tags: javascript, recursion

In a regular function, I can use the same result array in each iteration:

```js
_.unique = function(array) {
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (result.indexOf(array[i]) < 0) {
      result.push(array[i]);
    }
  }

  return result;
};
```

How can I do the same (and keep pushing to my result array) when working with a recursive function?

```js
_.unique = function(array) {

  var result = [];


  if (array.length === 0) {
    return result;
  } else {
    if (result.indexOf(array[0]) < 0) {
      result.push(array[0]);
    }
    return _.unique(array.slice(1));
  }

  return result;

};
```

Using this, I'm getting the wrong outputs. I can do this using a inside helper function, but I prefer not to.

Comment: If you want to share `result` between the recursions, you have to either pass it in with your function or declare it globally.

Comment: You probably want what's called tail recursion

Answer (score 1):

You must, pass the result to another function so the called function knows if the item is unique. In the following code example, the array of unique items is passed with the name `p_result`.

This is a working code example:

```
_.unique = function(array, p_result) {
    if(!(Object.prototype.toString.call(p_result) == '[object Array]')) p_result = [];

    var result = p_result;

    if(array.length === 0) return result;

    if(p_result.indexOf(array[0]) < 0) {
        result.push(array[0]);
    }

    return _.unique(array.slice(1), result);
};

// e.g. _.unique([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 7, 4]) gives [0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 4]
```

[Example fiddle that uses the code above](https://jsfiddle.net/5q5wvw0v/)

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that for your specific usecase a "_.uniq(array)" function already exists in underscore.js and lowdash.

Comment: I think the OP wants to re-implement the solution by using recursion. If you use recursion, you need to pass the array with unique result to the next function.

Comment: Yea I want to re-implement the underscore function using recursion, but this solution is giving me error?